# tokenize function is not reading the value from property in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I need to use tokenize function in my wso2 sequence file.
I am getting the username like testuser@gmail. I need to split the string using the delimeter @. I am using the below code.

        . But, It is always printing blank in logs. 
Could you please some one help me.

PS:: I have enabled xslt2.0 in my synapse.properties file.

Comment: Where is the "below code" ?

Comment: <property value="testuser@gmail" name="tokentest" scope="default"/>
        <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="NEW_CONTENT_TYPE" expression="fn:tokenize(syn:get-property('default','tokentest'),'@')[1]" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substring-before function

```
   <property name="tokentest" value="testuser@gmail" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NEW_CONTENT_TYPE" expression="substring-before($ctx:tokentest,'@')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="NEW_CONTENT" expression="$ctx:NEW_CONTENT_TYPE"/>
         </log>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still not working. Problem is, it is unable to read the value from tokentest. If is working with hard coded values.  Thanks Amit for providing help.

Comment: @hari1982 see my updated answer, try and let me know if there are any issues, I tested your scenario and it worked so it should work for you as well

Comment: Thanks Amit. Problem is resolved for me. The issue is i have defined the property under log element, which is not available for the next statement. I have moved out those statement from log, its started working. What i learned is, we should not define any element under log. log is just for to print the already defined elements.

Comment: yes @hari1982 log is normally used for the same purpose just to check whether the assigned variable is holding the right value or not, as you can see in the answer which i have provided after assigning value to an element i am just printing the value in the variable to be sure that expected values are going